# Get difference of foreign key attribute with django

Tags: django, django-orm

I'm trying to get a queryset where a Task has two Issuances which have been created within 10 seconds of one another.

Models are as follows:

```
Class Task(models.Model):
    # stuff

Class Issuance(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

What I've got so far:

```
qs = (
    Task.objects
    .annotate(count=Count('issuance'))
    .filter(count__gt=1, count__lte=2)
    .annotate(time_difference=F('issuance__created'))  # Need to fix this
    .annotate(
        dupe=Case(
            When(
                time_difference__lt=10,  # Less than 10 seconds
                then=Value(1),
            ),
            default=Value(0),
            output=BooleanField(),
        )
    )
)
```

I think I'm pretty close but I need some way to calculate the time difference between the creation date of the two issuances for any one Task. Also, need to do a comparison that the time delta is less than 10 seconds; not sure if what I have will work.

Can anyone help, please?

EDIT: Added output of query

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-e0e60776551e> in <module>()
     11             ),
     12             default=Value(0),
---> 13             output=BooleanField(),
     14         )
     15     )

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in annotate(self, *args, **kwargs)
    912                 raise ValueError("The annotation '%s' conflicts with a field on "
    913                                  "the model." % alias)
--> 914             clone.query.add_annotation(annotation, alias, is_summary=False)
    915 
    916         for alias, annotation in clone.query.annotations.items():

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py in add_annotation(self, annotation, alias, is_summary)
    969         """
    970         annotation = annotation.resolve_expression(self, allow_joins=True, reuse=None,
--> 971                                                    summarize=is_summary)
    972         self.append_annotation_mask([alias])
    973         self.annotations[alias] = annotation

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/expressions.py in resolve_expression(self, query, allow_joins, reuse, summarize, for_save)
    827         c.is_summary = summarize
    828         for pos, case in enumerate(c.cases):
--> 829             c.cases[pos] = case.resolve_expression(query, allow_joins, reuse, summarize, for_save)
    830         c.default = c.default.resolve_expression(query, allow_joins, reuse, summarize, for_save)
    831         return c

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/expressions.py in resolve_expression(self, query, allow_joins, reuse, summarize, for_save)
    760         c.is_summary = summarize
    761         if hasattr(c.condition, 'resolve_expression'):
--> 762             c.condition = c.condition.resolve_expression(query, allow_joins, reuse, summarize, False)
    763         c.result = c.result.resolve_expression(query, allow_joins, reuse, summarize, for_save)
    764         return c

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query_utils.py in resolve_expression(self, query, allow_joins, reuse, summarize, for_save)
     79         # We must promote any new joins to left outer joins so that when Q is
     80         # used as an expression, rows aren't filtered due to joins.
---> 81         clause, joins = query._add_q(self, reuse, allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=False)
     82         query.promote_joins(joins)
     83         return clause

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py in _add_q(self, q_object, used_aliases, branch_negated, current_negated, allow_joins, split_subq)
   1251                     child, can_reuse=used_aliases, branch_negated=branch_negated,
   1252                     current_negated=current_negated, connector=connector,
-> 1253                     allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,
   1254                 )
   1255                 joinpromoter.add_votes(needed_inner)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py in build_filter(self, filter_expr, branch_negated, current_negated, can_reuse, connector, allow_joins, split_subq)
   1141         clause = self.where_class()
   1142         if reffed_expression:
-> 1143             condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, reffed_expression, value)
   1144             clause.add(condition, AND)
   1145             return clause, []

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py in build_lookup(self, lookups, lhs, rhs)
   1081                     lhs = self.try_transform(lhs, name, lookups)
   1082                     final_lookup = lhs.get_lookup('exact')
-> 1083                 return final_lookup(lhs, rhs)
   1084             lhs = self.try_transform(lhs, name, lookups)
   1085             lookups = lookups[1:]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py in __init__(self, lhs, rhs)
     17     def __init__(self, lhs, rhs):
     18         self.lhs, self.rhs = lhs, rhs
---> 19         self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
     20         if hasattr(self.lhs, 'get_bilateral_transforms'):
     21             bilateral_transforms = self.lhs.get_bilateral_transforms()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py in get_prep_lookup(self)
     57             return self.rhs._prepare(self.lhs.output_field)
     58         if self.prepare_rhs and hasattr(self.lhs.output_field, 'get_prep_value'):
---> 59             return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
     60         return self.rhs
     61 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py in get_prep_value(self, value)
   1415 
   1416     def get_prep_value(self, value):
-> 1417         value = super(DateTimeField, self).get_prep_value(value)
   1418         value = self.to_python(value)
   1419         if value is not None and settings.USE_TZ and timezone.is_naive(value):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py in get_prep_value(self, value)
   1273     def get_prep_value(self, value):
   1274         value = super(DateField, self).get_prep_value(value)
-> 1275         return self.to_python(value)
   1276 
   1277     def get_db_prep_value(self, value, connection, prepared=False):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py in to_python(self, value)
   1376 
   1377         try:
-> 1378             parsed = parse_datetime(value)
   1379             if parsed is not None:
   1380                 return parsed

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/dateparse.py in parse_datetime(value)
     91     Returns None if the input isn't well formatted.
     92     """
---> 93     match = datetime_re.match(value)
     94     if match:
     95         kw = match.groupdict()

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: what are you getting now and does this query has any error?

Comment: @Exprator edited question to show the output

Comment: can you also show the fields in the Task model?

Comment: None of the fields on the Task model are related though. Is there something you're looking for?